# C++ Sleep() function

Tags: c++

Как Sleep() использует таймер на аппаратном уровне?

Comment: [На уровне диспетчера потоков OS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Т.е. сам вызов не трогает таймер.

Comment: В современных ОС на аппаратном уровне - никак не использует. Просто поток "говорит" планировщику, что столько-то времени его "не будить" (не передавать ему управление).